# Detecting scroll on iPad with jQuery only works when scrolling stops

Tags: jquery

I am testing this website on an iPad:
http://www.cherrystoneauctions.com/test

When you scroll the page down far enough that the navigation buttons with the blue marble background are above the top of your view area, I reposition those menus so they "stick" to the top of the screen:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    if ($('html').offset().top<-116){
        $('#fixnav').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $('#fixnav').removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
```

If you scroll back up, they "unstick" like normal.

This works pretty well on a computer screen, but with an iPad the "scroll" event is not triggered until the scrolling stops. So if you flick the screen with your finger, it will scroll, and once the scrolling stops, then it calculates the fixed/non-fixed navigation menu… which doesn't look good. I need it to basically calculate constantly, so it fixes/unfixes the menu immediately when the scroll goes past 116 pixels.

Is there a way I can have this trigger operate more smoothly on an iPad? Thanks!

Comment: It may not look good but at least it works well. Which is Apple's point this this "feature." If you aren't doing expensive re-draws when scrolling a page, the scroll can look really nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Mobile Safari, scroll events are suspended while scrolling to help increase performance, so your scroll handler only gets fired once, after scrolling stops. You'll want to use a scrolling library such as [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) to work around this limitation.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I should have specified Mobile Safari.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints which is a lot simpler. iScroll does many things and I'm sure would be useful for more complex things. Waypoints did the trick, very quickly.

Comment: I updated the answer to be more clear. FYI, `requestAnimationFrame` does fire, and is a good workaround for issues with `setInterval` and scrolling.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it's always appreciated to have more people in on the discussion. I updated the answer to remove some erroneous stuff.

Comment: I was interested in the `requestAnimationFrame` portion of your answer so I took a look at a site that I made that uses it in a few places and when I scroll on my iPad (iOS 6) the `requestAnimationFrame` code does not fire. How did you come to the opposite conclusion (I'm wondering if I did something wrong in my code)?

Comment: I've used several libraries that make use of it to do parallax (and other) scrolling effects, including iScroll. From my understanding, the one area where `requestAnimationFrame` doesn't fire correctly is when its called from within an `iframe`. Here's some more info on that bug: http://shitwebkitdoes.tumblr.com/post/47186945856/native-requestanimationframe-broken-on-ios-6 I'm not sure if this is fixed in iOS 7 as I haven't built anything targeting that yet.

Answer (score 3):

My fix for this was to use touch events rather than scroll events. The basic idea is:

1. Detect when a finger hits the screen (`touchstart`) and save the x/y coordinates of this. I also save the time so I can attempt to detect what the user is doing.
2. Detect when that finger moves and record where it moves to (`touchmove`). As the finger moves you can use this as your pseudo-`scroll` event handler. Where you take into account the current `scrollTop()` value as well as the amount of distance the user has moved their finger. Adding these together gives you your pseudo-scroll-position.
3. Detect when that finger leaves the screen surface and do your cleanup, e.g. delete the data taken for this scroll so you can start fresh next time.

Hope that helps. There will be caveats along the way but you're more than welcome to come back and ask those questions on Stack Overflow.